# Customizing calender in a web part

Tags: sharepoint-designer

[image]

I have a calendar in my SharePoint 2013 site. I want to use it in a web part. The way I want the items to display is the following:

- The Title of the calendar.
- The Location of the event.
- Start Time - End Time.
- The Month and Date has to be shown like in the image above.

Here are my thoughts on this:
I am thinking of using jQuery to get the month and date from the calendar item and adding to the black image on the appropriate places.

My questions are:

- Am I on the right track?
- Are there other ways of doing this?
- And if someone has come up with a similar issue, can they kindly explain how it was done.

Answer (score 0):

[image: DateImage]
Please save the image to a location on your sharepoint site. The image name is DayImage.png

```
  <style type="text/css">
```

.images{
    background-image:url('../DayImage.png'); 
    height: 55px; 
    width: 48px;

}
.images, .events{
margin-bottom:10px;
}
.events{
padding-left:10px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.months{
    color:white; 
    font-size:11px; 
    margin-left:0px; 
    margin-top:0px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;

}
.dates{
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:-5px;
    font-size:29px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
.title, .location, .time{
Font-size: 12px;
}
.udFullCalendar A:link, .udFullCalendar A:hover, .udFullCalendar A:visited
{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    white-space:no-wrap;
}

.events A:link, .events A:hover, .events A:visited
{
    text-decoration:none;
}

```
</style>
```

$(document).ready(function() {

getCalendarListItems();

```
});
```

function getCalendarListItems() {

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
        clientCalContext = new SP.ClientContext();
        var camlQ= new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQ.set_viewXml('100');

```
    var oweb = clientCalContext.get_web();
    var olists = oweb.get_lists();
    var olist = olists.getByTitle(<name of your calendar>);

    colListItem = olist.getItems(camlQ);
    clientCalContext.load(colListItem, 'Include(ID, EventDate, EndDate, Location, Title)');

    clientCalContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, OnSuccess),
    Function.createDelegate(this, OnFail)); 
});
```

}
   function OnSuccess() {

var array_month =       ["JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"];
var listiteminfo='';
listiteminfo += '';
var liEnum = colListItem.getEnumerator();

```
while(liEnum.moveNext())
{
    var oLiCal=liEnum.get_current();                                   
    var eventDate = oLiCal.get_item('EventDate');       
    var eventDateString = String(eventDate.getDate());      
    var eventMonth = eventDate.getMonth();


    var eventHour = am_pm(eventDate.getHours());
    var endHour = am_pm((oLiCal.get_item('EndDate')).getHours());

    if(eventDateString.length < 2)
      {
         eventDateString = "0" + eventDateString;
      }

      var LocationHTML="";
      var LinkHTML = '<a href="../Lists/UpcomingDates/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + oLiCal.get_item('ID') + '">';
      if(oLiCal.get_item('Location'))
      {
        LocationHTML='<div class="location">' +oLiCal.get_item('Location') + '</div>';
      }

    listiteminfo +=     '<tr>';
    listiteminfo +=        '<td>';
    listiteminfo +=           '<div class="images">';
    listiteminfo +=             '<div class="months">' + array_month[eventMonth] + '</div>';
    listiteminfo +=             '<div class="dates">' + eventDateString + '</div>';
    listiteminfo +=           '</div>';
    listiteminfo +=       '</td>';
    listiteminfo +=       '<td class="calEvents">';
    listiteminfo +=        '<div class="events">' + LinkHTML;
    listiteminfo +=          '<div class="title">' + oLiCal.get_item('Title') + '</div>';
    listiteminfo +=          LocationHTML;
    listiteminfo +=          '<div class="time">' +eventHour + ' - ' + endHour + '</div>';  
    listiteminfo +=        '</a></div>';
    listiteminfo +=       '</td>';      
    listiteminfo +=     '</tr>';

}
```

listiteminfo += 'Full Calendar';

$("#calendarGoesHere").html(listiteminfo);
}

function OnFail() {

}
function am_pm(time)
{
var _time = Number(time);
_time += 1;
    if((_time - 12) >= 0)
    {
         if(_time > 12)
             {_time = _time - 12;}

```
    _time = String(_time);
    _time += " pm";
}
else{
_time = String(_time);
_time += " am";
}
return _time;
```

}

```
 <div id="calendarGoesHere"></div>
```